# Container view is covering my image view

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicontainerview

I have a containerView that should be hidden by an imageView by default, at start up the image should cover the container. however, even though the layering in IB is correct and the imageView is updated after the container the container is still showing up in front of the image. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Here is the outline of IB:

[image]

I when I first posted this, I had the Image View, and the three buttons on a View within the main view. but since then, I have changed it to how it is shown.

Given the I have outlets for each subview as follows: Container View-Container, Image View-backgroundImage, Buttons-item1, item2, item3.

Here is a list of things I have tried:

1. `[self.view sendSubviewToBack: _Container];`
2. `[self.view bringSubviewToFront: _item1];`
3. `[self.view bringSubviewToFront: _item2];`
4. `[self.view bringSubviewToFront: _item3];`
5. `[self.view bringSubviewToFront: _backgroundImage];`

I have also tried to move the container view out from the visible coordinates of the view controller but this did not work either.

Also here is my viewDidAppear method for the View Controller:

First I set up the container view, and then I do some initial setup for the buttons and image view. At the bottom of this method is where I have been putting the subview commands.
Hopefully this will help.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewDidAppear:animated];
[self.containerViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"embedConverter" sender:nil];

_item1.center = self.view.center;
_item2.center = self.view.center;
_item3.center = self.view.center;
_item1.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5,1.5);
_item3.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5,-.5);

CGAffineTransform move1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -15);
CGAffineTransform move3 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 15);

_item1.transform = move1;
_item3.transform = move3;

[_item1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[_item2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[_item3 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.25, 1.25);

_item1.transform = scale;
_item2.transform = scale;
_item3.transform = scale;

_item1.alpha = menuAlpha;
_item2.alpha = menuAlpha;
_item3.alpha = menuAlpha;

_menuBackground.image = [self applyBlurWithRadius:10
                                        tintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:.3 alpha:.7]
                            saturationDeltaFactor:1
                                        maskImage:nil];
```

}

Comment: Please provide a screen shot to _prove_ that "the layering in IB is correct".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the title of your question, the troublesome view is *not* the container view. It is staying where you put it. The troublesome view is a *different* view, an extra *contained* view that doesn't appear in the storyboard screen shot - because an embed segue or some other form of parent-child view controller containment is involved.

It may be that you have used an embed segue without really understanding what it is. I notice you have a container view *and* a container view controller *and* some other view controllers. It may be that you have confused yourself.

One possible starting solution might be to delete (comment out) this line:

```
[self.containerViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"embedConverter" sender:nil];
```

- It is unnecessary. You already have an embed segue from the container view, and this will be performed automatically. If the container view is not automatically loading the correct view controller and its view, you've got this set up wrong in the storyboard (too many levels of containment, perhaps).
- This is a parent-child view controller relationship. This means that the child view controller is going to come along and its view, which is a totally new view, is going to be injected into your interface. This explains why you can't control the front-to-back position of the view! You can mess with the "container view" all you like, but that is *not the view you are seeing which is causing the trouble* - the view that's causing the trouble is the *new* view. Thus, you are bringing the image view to the front, but then this new view is being injected *in front of everything*.

However, I would go even further. By using an embed segue, you have given up all control over the layering order of the injected view. I would suggest that you ask yourself two questions:

1. Do I really need a parent-child view controller relationship at all? In many cases, the answer is no. For example, let's say you want a little table view inside your interface. Some people think that this requires a table view controller and an embed segue. But that's not so; a table view controller is never necessary, and you can manage the table as a view perfectly will with your
2. If the answer to (1) is really yes, then would I be better off managing this relationship - *and the resulting injected view* - manually?

If you did (2), you wouldn't need the container view and you'd be in total control of where and how the injected view is placed into your interface.

Comment: And here's my discussion of how to manage a parent-child view controller relationship (and the view) manually: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: But really, consider _not_ using this. You might be happier with just _one_ view controller and everything else just views that it manages.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, it was extremely helpful. I just have a few questions. I will have some my main view controller with its own view, then that view will have some subviews (buttons and an image view) these views will be there permanently, this will act as a menu. but then I will have several other possible views that will be full screen, my question is, when bringing in these child views later on will I still be able to make them come in as a layer in the back of my menu views?

Comment: That's a whole new question. Ask a whole new question! What I tried to do was answer the question you asked here, namely, why is this view appearing in front of my image view. I think I've successfully explained that.

Comment: Also I am really new to this so could you explain how I keep references to my child view controllers? I assume this must be done in IB because otherwise you will not have access to them while the program is running, right? anyways where exactly do I make this reference?

Comment: Please stop pursuing this in comments. Just because someone tries to give you an answer, you must not bully them into giving further information. This is called a "help vampire". Formulate a _new_ question, carefully, and then ask it separately as a _question_.